# I am getting an unknown message while running npm start, Please guide

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

I am running `npm start` command after creating a new react app but today I am getting these lines in the terminal. I don't know whether it is an error or something else. I have searched about this but couldn't find anything helping. Please guide me about this. Thank you!

**Error:**

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view material-ui-demo in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.106:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

asset static/js/bundle.js 1.92 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset index.html 1.8 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 190 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 5.56 MiB (javascript) 28.2 KiB (runtime) [cached] 6143 modules
webpack 5.65.0 compiled successfully in 8393 ms
```

Comment: Hi, can you [please post the output as plaintext in your question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) Thank you.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger I am sorry. I have replaced the screenshot with text. You can now see it.

Comment: So what happens when you go to: http://localhost:3000/ on the browser? (The log above looks like a successful new project compilation). Please note to use http, and not https while reaching this dev server.

Comment: @YanivPeretz It compiles successfully and the app runs properly, but I never saw this message before yesterday. Therefore, I was a little bit worried. I am also seeing this message while running my old react apps.

Comment: Im viewing this message since i update to node 16, but all is working fine in dev and production.

Comment: These lines are not errors, they are just logs.

Comment: I got it. Thank you all of you!